# How different classloaders resolve reference

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

If i create a custom class loader for say 3(A,B,C) classes of my Java app and redirect all other loading to default bootstrap class loader. Then according to JVM spec :
  "A reference to a class is consulted from current class loader and loaded (if necessary ) accordingly"

Now if i try to create object of class D(whose Class-Loader reference is bootstrap in "Class" class) from class A(whose Class-Loader reference is custom loader) , then custom-loader does not have any way to find path of D.class file (say i pick A,B,C from internet / some other place in which case , CLASSPATH is different in custom loader).

So how does this class finding problem would be resolved by JVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement your custom classloader correctly there will be no problem. All classloaders have a parent. For a custom classloader it's typically the system class loader, the one that loads classes from Java class path. Typically classloader first of all offers (delegates) its parent to load a class and only if the parent fails then it tries to load the class. To make this happen custom classloader needs to implement `findClass` method and the delegation will be done automatically by ClassLoader.loadClass.

Note that JVM has not only bootstrap class loader but a hierarchy of three class loaders

bootstrap <- extension <- system

Comment: (May also be worth noting that sometimes `null` is used to represent the bootstrap class loader and sometimes the system class loader - they were the same thing in Java 1.0/1.1.)